# Поиск и удаление из текста преобразованных html символов

Tags: php

Необходимо очистить текст, в котором есть в большом количестве замененные *html*-символы.

Например: `&lt;h2&gt; &lt;p&gt;`

Как это можно сделать?

Поискал в интернете, но толковой информации не нашел. Сделать надо это, конечно же при помощи *PHP*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями. Если очистить(удалить, тогда)

```
$sometext = "&lt;h2&gt; &lt;p&gt";
return preg_replace('/(&lt;|&gt;)/', '', $sometext);
```

Больше информации [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6073221/2546083)

Сформировать regexp выражение с помощью [онлайн сервисов](http://www.regexr.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже посоветовали в комментах к другому ответу - используйте функцию [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode), она преобразует сущности в их html-эквиваленты. (`&lt;` в `<` и т.д.)

Так как неясно что вы имеете в виду под словом **очистить** - то можно остановиться на этом. Если же вы хотите удалить все html-теги из текста - используйте [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags)

Answer (score 0):

А какие тут могут быть предложения? Начать надо с алгоритма.

`&lt;` - это `<` (less than), а `&gt;` - это `>` (greater than).
Согласно алгоритму надо искать в тексте сочетания этих символов и на выдаче менять их на `< >`, соответственно.

Как это сделать в php вы должны знать сами, раз уж пишете не php.

Comment: для этого есть  html_entity_decode

Comment: @splash58, наверное есть. Я не специалист в php. Просто ответил на вопрос из категории _"лень думать самому, напишите за меня"._

Comment: на самом деле, я не очень понял, что значит `очистить` :)

Comment: @splash58, насколько я понял, у коллеги есть приблизительно такой текст `a quick &lt;b&gt;brown fox&lt;/b&gt; jumps over the lazy dog`. Ему надо поменять референц-символы HTML на обычные теги `<>`, воспринимаемые браузером. Это простейшие операции строковой замены.